# Next Auth And SWR

Tags: next.js, next-auth, swr

i use next auth for authentication and swr for data fetching . everything is go good but problem is when refresh the page next auth take couple second to get session to client side so SWR is fetch brfore that .

is there any way to wait until session load done swr fetch after that ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont want to delete this. after i found some way :
i check for session.user in userSession funtion so if not show laoding and after that show page that is it